# Change kendo ui editor on keypress

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I am using kendo ui editor with angularjs,

```
<textarea kendo-editor
    k-on-change="vm.bodyIsDirty = true"
    k-options="vm.editorOptions" 
    ng-model="vm.myModel"
    style="height: 320px;">
</textarea>
```

I can see from the documentation that corresponding model is been updated on blur event, I need to have it updated on keypress is that possible ?

Comment: Based on the [documentation](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor), it does not appear that can be changed. However, there's nothing stopping you from hooking up [`ngKeypress`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeypress) and doing what you need to do.

Comment: Thanks, ng-keypress doesn't seems to work with kendo-editor,
 http://dojo.telerik.com/akozI

Answer (score 0):

Use the k-on-keyup event, where 'updateNgModel()' is a function defined in your $scope in the controller

Example:

```
<div id="example" ng-app="KendoDemos">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
            <textarea kendo-editor id="editor" k-on-keyup="updateNgModel()" k-ng-model="html"></textarea>

        <div class="box wide">
            <textarea ng-bind-html="html" style="width: 100%; height: 5em"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  angular.module("KendoDemos", [ "kendo.directives", "ngSanitize" ])
      .controller("MyCtrl", function($scope){
          $scope.html = "<h1>Kendo Editor</h1>\n\n" +
          "<p>Note that 'change' is triggered when the editor loses focus.\n" +
              "<br /> That's when the Angular scope gets updated.</p>";

           $scope.updateNgModel= function() {
               $scope.html = $("#editor").data("kendoEditor").value();
           }
      })
</script>
```